# How to compare values of same element(input text field) and remove duplication if exist?

Tags: php, jquery

I am assigning numbers to different vehicles. There are duplication occurs which I don't want. I need the numbers to be unique for every vehicle. Below is my code for assigning numbers to vehicles.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    // get order details //
    $order_id=$_GET['post'];
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
    // Iterating through each "line" items in the order //
    $order_count=count($order->get_items());
    echo '<div class="driver_licences">';
    $count=1;
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
        $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity();
        for($i=1; $i<=$item_quantity; $i++){
            $driver_assigned_cart = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'driver_cart'.$count, true ) ? get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'driver_cart'.$count, true ) : '';
            // input field for assigning Cart number //
            echo '<lable>Driver '.$count.' assigned cart NO#</label>
            <input class="unique_cart_number" type="text"  name="driver_cart'.$count.'" value="'.$driver_assigned_cart.'">';
            $count++;
        }
    }
        echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: use array_unique on array which you are using in foreach loop

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your title and your question body do not seem to agree. Your title is asking about removing duplicates, whereas the body seems to be asking about generating unique values. Can you clarify, by editing your question?

Comment: The code above only assign numbers to vehicles. There is no restriction on assigning duplicate yet. I only want to know how to restrict my input field to not assign any duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with unique id.Which will give unique values only for every execution

Instead of for loop you can use it inside your foreach loop.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  $uid = uniqid();
  echo $uid.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.unique_cart_number').on('change', function(e) {
    var stored  =   [];
    var inputs  =   $('.unique_cart_number');
        $.each(inputs,function(k,v){
            var getVal  =   $(v).val();
            if(stored.indexOf(getVal) != -1)
        alert('duplicate cart numbers exists. please remove duplication.');
            else
            stored.push($(v).val());
            });
                });
        $('.save_order').on('click', function(e) {
            var stored  =   [];
            var inputs  =   $('.unique_cart_number');
            $.each(inputs,function(k,v){
            var getVal  =   $(v).val();
            if(stored.indexOf(getVal) != -1){
            alert('duplicate cart numbers exists. please remove duplication.');
            e.preventdefault();
            }
            else
            stored.push($(v).val());
            });
            });
            });
</script>
```